# Understanding Keras weight matrix of each layers

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to do a binary classification using Fully Connected Layer architecture in Keras which is called as Dense class in Keras.

Here is the design of Neural Network architecture I created:

```
 from keras.models import Sequential
        from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
        from keras.optimizers import SGD

        self.model = Sequential()
        # Dense(64) is a fully-connected layer with 64 hidden units.
        # in the first layer, you must specify the expected input data shape:
        # here, 20-dimensional vectors.
        self.model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=self.x_train_std.shape[1]))
        #self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        #self.model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        #self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        self.model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

So I have an input matrix of 17000,2000 which 17K samples with 2k features.

I have kept only one hidden layer with 32 units or neurons in that.

My output layer is a one neuron with sigmoid activation function.

Now when I try to check the weights of first hidden layer I am expecting it to be of size (2000,32) where each row is for each input and each column is for each unit in that layer.

Here is the config of the architecture setup by Keras:

```
dl_1.model.get_config()
Out[70]:
[{'class_name': 'Dense',
  'config': {'activation': 'relu',
   'activity_regularizer': None,
   'batch_input_shape': (None, 2000),
   'bias_constraint': None,
   'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}},
   'bias_regularizer': None,
   'dtype': 'float32',
   'kernel_constraint': None,
   'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling',
    'config': {'distribution': 'uniform',
     'mode': 'fan_avg',
     'scale': 1.0,
     'seed': None}},
   'kernel_regularizer': None,
   'name': 'dense_1',
   'trainable': True,
   'units': 32,
   'use_bias': True}},
 {'class_name': 'Dense',
  'config': {'activation': 'sigmoid',
   'activity_regularizer': None,
   'bias_constraint': None,
   'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}},
   'bias_regularizer': None,
   'kernel_constraint': None,
   'kernel_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling',
    'config': {'distribution': 'uniform',
     'mode': 'fan_avg',
     'scale': 1.0,
     'seed': None}},
   'kernel_regularizer': None,
   'name': 'dense_2',
   'trainable': True,
   'units': 1,
   'use_bias': True}}]
```

To see the dimension of first hidden layer:

```
dl_1.model.get_layer(name="dense_1").input_shape

(None, 2000)
```

Output size:

```
    dl_1.model.get_layer(name="dense_1").output_shape
Out[99]:
(None, 32)
```

So it does seem to give the (2000,32) which is as expected.

However when I try to check the weight matrix for this layer

```
dl_1.model.get_layer(name="dense_1").get_weights()[0]
```

It gives me a list of numpy arrays with list length being 2000 and array length inside that 32 like below:

```
array([[ 0.0484077 , -0.02401097, -0.03099879, -0.02864455, -0.01511723,
         0.01386002,  0.01127522,  0.00844895, -0.02420873,  0.04466306,
         0.02965425,  0.0410631 ,  0.02397312,  0.0038885 ,  0.04846045,
         0.00653989, -0.05288456, -0.00325713,  0.0445733 ,  0.04594839,
         0.02839083,  0.0445912 , -0.0140048 , -0.01198476,  0.05259909,
        -0.03752745, -0.01337494, -0.02162734, -0.01522341,  0.01208428,
         0.01122886,  0.01496441],
       [ 0.05225918,  0.04231448,  0.01388102, -0.03310467, -0.05293509,
         0.01130457,  0.03127011, -0.04250741, -0.04212657, -0.01595866,
        -0.002456  ,  0.01112743,  0.0150629 ,  0.03072598, -0.04061607,
        -0.01131565, -0.02259113,  0.00907649, -0.04728404, -0.00909081,
         0.03182121, -0.04608218, -0.04411709, -0.03561752,  0.04686243,
        -0.04555761,  0.04087613,  0.04380137,  0.02079088, -0.02390963,
        -0.0164928 , -0.01228274],
```

I am not sure I understand this. It should be 32 X2000 and not 2000 X 32. So I am expecting that since I have 32 units, and each unit has 2000 weights, the list would be 32 elements long and each element should be 2000 dimension numpy array. But it's reverse. I am not sure why is that?

The weights are associated with the hidden layer and not the input layer so if I think they showed it for input layer that doesn't make sense.

Any idea what is going on in this?

Comment: There is nothing going on, its just a matter of notation and convention.

Comment: Yeah I am understanding that. But isn't this a inconvenient convention? Think about it. When I say I want to check the weights of a layer, it basically means I want to find out for each unit in that layer what are the weights. It also gives me flexibility in indexing by unit (1, 2, 3,,) for a layer and then find out all the weights for that unit. But now, the way Keras has, it's by a unit of previous layer, which means

Answer (score 6):

You are creating a `Dense()` layer of 32 units. `Dense` layers are (as your comment in the code indicates) "fully-connected layers", that means each feature in the data is connected to every layer. You also have 2000 features in your data elements.

Therefore the array you are getting has 2000 elements, one for each feature, and each one with 32 weights, one for each hidden layer, hence the shape you get.

From the [keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/core/) we can see the example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(16,)))
# now the model will take as input arrays of shape (*, 16)
# and output arrays of shape (*, 32)

# after the first layer, you don't need to specify
# the size of the input anymore:
model.add(Dense(32))
```

In your case `*` is 2000 so your output weights should be of shape `(2000,32)` as you are getting. This seems to be the convention Keras uses for their outputs. Either way you could transform your data to give it other shapes, as a `(N, M)` array has the same number of elements as a `(M, N)` array.

Comment: That is the point. The weights are not for features. The weights are defined for a neuron which uses those features. What you are saying is that for input layer it is giving this output when in actuality it should be showing this for hidden layer. Each hidden layer has 32 units and each unit has a 2000 weights incident on it. So ideally it should be a list of 32 elements for each neuron and each element being 2000 array for 2000 feature.

Comment: "ideally it should be..." ...Well maybe you are right and it could be 32x2000, however note that either way (32x2000 or 2000x32) you still have the same information even though it is with different shape. You could even reshape it to be of the one of your preference. It surely is the convention that the developers decided to use.

Comment: Edited my question further based on my previous comment and some documentation

Comment: Well I saw your edit. Something is not right. I have an input data of 17000 x 2000. In your code, you say 16 is the no. of features of input data. For me the no. of features are 2000 and 17k samples. The weights are stored for each layer as (no. of features * no. of units) So it should be (2000 X 32). I think I get it now. They are giving the output as weights matrix which is 2000 *32. Hence the length of list 2000. However think from the machine learning perspective.

Comment: When you say, access the weights of each layer, one would want to access what is the weights associated with each unit of the layer. Which means from the developer perspective, he wants to know for each unit what are the weights. So then it would have made sense to have 32 X2000 since now one can say for each unit I have 2000 weights.

Comment: @Baktaawar I agree with you, knowing the weight of each hidden unit is important, specially when you want to understand your model and problem deeper (as those units with greater weights give some notion of the Principal Components of your features). If you want to get that insight you will have to transform the data and group the weights per layer, so yes it is not straightforward to obtain that data.

Comment: It can surely be a possible feature request or improvement for Keras. You could try ask for it by posting an issue in the Keras Git issues [page](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues). Hopefully they will add it :) Anyways, did my answer solved your question?